# Why does an insert using EF code first fail within a TransactionScope?

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, transactions, entity-framework-4.1

I have a situation where I create a record in one table (asset_type) and reference it via a foreign key in a second table (asset).  Both of these inserts, in this situation, occur within the same TransactionScope.

When using a raw DbConnection, the inserts are successful:

```
conn.ConnectionString = "host=localhost;port=5432;database=test_client_alpha;user id=tcauser;password=tcapw";    

using (var trans = new TransactionScope())
{
  conn.Open();
  conn.EnlistTransaction(Transaction.Current);

  var cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
  cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO overview.asset_type ( name ) VALUES( 'Unknown' ) RETURNING id";
  var assetTypeId = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

  cmd.CommandText = string.Format("INSERT INTO overview.asset "
                                  + "(asset_type_id, client_id, is_active, is_gps_active, is_virtual, default_lon, default_lat) "
                                  + "VALUES ({0}, 'mid', TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 0, 0 ) "
                                  + "RETURNING id ", assetTypeId);
  var assetId = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

  trans.Complete();
}
```

However, if I switch to using a DbContext class, the second insert (into asset) fails with a foreign key constraint violation as though the first insert (into asset_type) did not happen:

```
conn.ConnectionString = "host=localhost;port=5432;database=test_client_alpha;user id=tcauser;password=tcapw";

using (var trans = new TransactionScope())
{
  using (var context = new TestContext(conn, false))
  {
    var assetTypeId = context.Database
      .SqlQuery<int>("INSERT INTO overview.asset_type ( name ) VALUES( 'Unknown' ) RETURNING id")
      .Single();

    var assetId = context.Database
      .SqlQuery<int>(string.Format("INSERT INTO overview.asset "
                                    + "(asset_type_id, client_id, is_active, is_gps_active, is_virtual, default_lon, default_lat) "
                                    + "VALUES ({0}, 'mid', TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, 0, 0 ) "
                                    + "RETURNING id ", assetTypeId))
      .Single();
    trans.Complete();
  }
}
```

If I remove the TransactionScope, the DbContext example executes normally.

I have tried playing with the IsolationLevel settings (ReadCommitted, ReadUncommitted) with no success.

I realize that I don't need a TransactionScope in this example.  This is part of a larger chunk of code that involves interaction with multiple databases and requires a distributed transaction.

My database is PostgreSQL and I am using DevArt's dotConnect .NET drivers.

Does anyone have any insight into why the DbContext example does not work?

Comment: I've never really used the raw SQL methods of DbContext but isn't `SqlQuery` only for READ operations (queries) and `ExecuteSqlCommand` for DML like INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE? But then I'm surprised that you don't get an exception.

Comment: I've tested a similar code (but same logic: Insert row1 in table1 and then insert row2 in table2 with FK to row1) with SQL Server and SQLClient as provider. It worked both with and without `TransactionScope`. The problem might have to do with PostgreSQL or the dotConnect driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Managing Connections and Transactions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896325.aspx):

> The Entity Framework opens connections only when required, for example to execute a query or to call SaveChanges, and then closes the connection when the operation is complete.

- Calling any of the following methods opens the connection:
- SaveChanges or Refresh on ObjectContext.
- FirstOrDefault, or First on ObjectQuery.
- Load on EntityCollection.
- Load on EntityReference.
- Any Language-Integrated Query (LINQ) method or ObjectQuery query builder method, such as Where, OrderBy, or Select.

And then it opens another one connection, transaction scope throw exception. You must setup the [`Distributed Transaction Coordinator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684146%28VS.85%29.aspx) (can't say is it real or not for the PostgreSQL).

If it is real, then, after setup the DTC simply open your `conn` object inside the scope.

Comment: I see, so manage the connection lifetime manually inside the scope of the context?

Comment: @Chris Hogan Yes, if Transaction Scope is required.